# Evaluate mit-scheme code block in org-mode with geiser and babel

Tags: emacs, scheme, org-mode, mit-scheme

I am attempting to replicate the code in "The Little Schemer" as I follow along and am running into errors.

.emacs file:

```
;; Melpa package contains geiser
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-unstable" . "http://melpa.org/packages/" t)
(package-initialize)

;; Setup geiser and babel
(require 'scheme)
(require 'python)
(setq geiser-active-implementations '(mit))
(custom-set-variables
 '(scheme-program-name "mit-scheme"))
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((scheme . t)
   (python . t)
   (sh . t)))
```

I run M-x geiser. This opens up a fully functional Mit REPL. But when I evaluate my scheme src code block, the following occurs:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC scheme
(define lat?
  (lamda (l)
    (cond
     ((null? l) #T)
     ((atom? (car l)) (lat? (cdr l)))
     (else #f))))
(lat? (bacon and eggs))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: An error ocurred.
```

I am in org-mode when running C-c C-c.

UPDATE: I have switched environments from my Ubuntu VM to Cygwin. I followed [uileiknarf's Cygwin Emacs guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kac90A1UzD0) with great success. My learning experience is back on track!

Comment: Are you sure this runs in MIT directly? That should be `lambda`, for instance.

Comment: What version of org-mode are you running? Commit 96b410f8 fixed one egregious error in ob-scheme, but there may very well be others. That is included in 9.0.3 (actually in any 9.0.x version), but if you are running 8.x, you probably don't have it. But note, that  even if you *do* have it, there is no guarantee that it will work: ob-scheme is buggy and does not have many users so far, so if you can submit bug reports to the ML, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Your `scheme` code should be something like this:

```
(define lat?
  (lambda (l)
    (cond
     ((null? l) #t)
     ((not (pair? (car l)))
      (lat? (cdr l)))
     (else #f))))

(lat? '(bacon and eggs))
```

Possibly that will run without errors.

Comment: No, unfortunately the typo is not the real problem: even when fixed, ob-scheme fails to evaluate things properly. As I said, it is buggy.